How do I synchronize thousands of game object transforms?
I'm trying to synchronize 3-4 thousand game objects' positions and rotations. I need performance for my Unity game to remain relatively high (30+fps) and to keep the amount of data sent as low as possible. Therefore I need a solution for sending large amounts of data from the server to the clients with as little data and overhead as possible. I don't want to be paying massive server costs and making the server lag due to too much traffic being sent.
To explain what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to synchronize the destruction of a building across clients. Also, important note, I only need to send data to the clients, I don't need to send any data back to the server (I assumed this would be simple for the server as all it had to do was mass blast all clients with the current game object transform data).
I'm aware that there are tricks to keep traffic low or reduce the need to sync as often such as "client prediction and server side reconciliation", which I plan to look into at a later point (although this could add overhead that perhaps I don't need).
I'm aware that there have been solutions in certain games (I believe) that involve using multiple servers to sync building destruction, but I'd appreciate a single server solution if possible.
I'm also aware that there are probably solutions for avoiding syncing unnecessary game objects that a client may not see such as NetworkProximityChecker, but assuming that all game objects that are being synced are visible and active, I need a solution for handling that (in the worst case scenario that clients can see all the game objects being synced at some point).
Things I've thought about doing are avoiding using NetworkTransforms or even NetworkBehaviours altogether and sending simple NetworkBase/NetworkMessage (I believe it's called) messages to the clients (to reduce data sent). Or, go even more basic and use non-Unity libraries to send data to clients (again to avoid overhead and too much data being sent that might create too much large traffic).
There may not be a solution to this that works well - there is no getting around the simple fact that Vector3s and Quaternions must be constantly sent to each client, and there isn't a way to avoid that massive amounts of data being sent.
I'm using Unity Mirror, although I could and probably will switch to Unity's netcode.
So far, I've tried using Unity Mirror's NetworkIdentity and NetworkTransforms to sync all the necessary object's transforms. With two players the performance wasn't too bad, but not great. With 4 players performance was pretty horrible, with fps around the mid teens.
I was expecting this considering how much data was being sent.
update. game details:
to give more details about the game; players will be walking around a map of destructible buildings that will cause obstacles for them. therefore i need all the broken building parts to be synced. i could only sync parts that're close to players, but in the rare event that there is a lot of destruction all occurring in close proximity to all players, this plan falls apart. I want to ensure the game can handle this uncommon occurrence.
i know that relative to other games sending a ton of data won't be cheap, but cutting the amount of data sent by half could mean reducing cost for running the game, increasing performance (fps) by a lot, and reducing network traffic by a lot. Even small efficiencies i think could come close to making or breaking the game. For example, a 15 - 20 fps game isn't really playable in my opinion but a 28 - 30 fps is. If I could increase performance during these worst case situations of massive destruction even that relatively small amount, that'd be enough.

Is the destruction deterministic enough that you might only need to sent the data on how it starts and from there you could simulate it fully on the client?

I agree with @Zibelas from what I know most large games send stuff like this in the form of triggers and simulate on the client side. This would heavily cut down on server strain as its using the clients device to simulate it not the server itself and would also heavily cut down on data transmission size.

i'm going to run all the movement and physics collisions/simulations on the server. I need full physics simulations for all the gameObjects running on the server, and the clients will only have to receive the most recent transform data. To answer the question, the clients can not handle anything themselves, they must receive all position/rotation data from the server.

if you guys are correct and the simulation can be done on the client side, what happens if the simulation of building destruction is different between server and client? how does an issue of position get handled/resolved/reconciled on the client sides?

That's why Zibelas led with "is the destruction deterministic?" You want to arrange things so that an unmodified client can only arrive at the same result as the server, and no other result. (You don't care if someone modifies their client and gets a mismatched result, because that only harms their own experience. Server authority on character movement / other actions ensures they can't gain gameplay advantage by skewing their destruction simulation). I'd strongly advise looking for strategies like this to avoid synchronizing the majority of these parts over the network if at all feasible.

i wasn't sure exactly what deterministic meant. but i figured by stating i needed the server to have authority to ensure appropriate gameobject placement that'd answer the question.

but i heard what you're saying @DMGregory, i absolutely want to reduce as much passing of data from server to client for this simulation as possible, but i can see that players could gain gameplay advantages over others if for example a piece of destroyed building were to land at some advantageous position for some players and not others. Do you believe that physics simulations for a crumbling building would play out the same for both client and server? i get the feeling they wouldn't; but i could be wrong.  however, assuming no other option, what's the most efficient way to send tons of data?

It would not be possible to gain advantage for a player. The physic simulation will happen on both server and client, but you don't sync the actual pieces. Your destruction code would need to be written in a way that the same input always gives the same output result. You could still cheat if that is not fully working by transmitting only the end position of the piece if you don't care too much how it gets there and let the client interpolate the way. But that will depend on the game play of your game

I think you're unlikely to find a solution that you can just plug in at the netcode layer that will suddenly make synchronizing thousands of positions and orientations "cheap". So, I think you should widen your focus to consider ways you can avoid needing to synchronize thousands of objects. Determinism is one option. Another is to divide your building pieces into gameplay-affecting large chunks and gameplay-irrelevant small bits, and only synchronize the gameplay-important chunks, biasing your destruction to only spawn a few of them. We'd need more details about your game to help with this.

@TonyThaDee "I need full physics simulations for all the gameObjects running on the server". Why? Is this an unavoidable constraint, or rather a design requirement one may work around somehow while giving the "illusion" of simulated physics?

i'm planning for the worst case scenario in which i absolutely must sync all building-destroyed-components. therefore, i just want to find the way to transmit transform data the cheapest way possible (since the only functionality i need is transform syncing) for a worst case scenario situation. the game requirements are that all destruction is interact-able for players. @DMGregory I could break up gameobjects into chunks, but the problem is determining which group to put them in. players must be allowed to choose any bit of destroyed building to interact with.

to give more details about the game; players will be walking around a map of destructible buildings that will cause obstacles for them. therefore i need all the broken building parts to be synced. i could only sync parts that're close to players, but in the rare event that there is a lot of destruction all occurring in close proximity to all players, this plan falls apart. I want to ensure the game can handle this uncommon occurrence.

i know that relative to other games sending a ton of data won't be cheap, but cutting the amount of data sent by half could mean reducing cost for running the game, increasing performance (fps) by a lot, and reducing network traffic by a lot. Even small efficiencies i think could come close to making or breaking the game. For example, a 15 - 20 fps game isn't really playable in my opinion but a 28 - 30 fps is. If I could increase performance during these worst case situations of massive destruction even that relatively small amount, that'd be enough.

That looks like information to edit into your question, so it's not missed buried several replies down in a comment thread.

@DMGregory I figured that since the only requirement is mass blasting all clients the current position/rotation of each fragmented building component; that this should be pretty simple. for example, perhaps a simple solution involving basic c# sockets could work. any overhead or complexity might perhaps reduce performance because it'd be too slow. Perhaps a plug and play solution isn't necessary. i don't know, do you guys think a solution like using the system.net.sockets library could reduce data sizes sent and increase speed/performance,or would netcode or mirror do a better or the same job?

@Zibelas i think the only way to determine if all the clients would have the same output from the destruction is to depend on the physics playing out the same for all of them. That's fine, but i don't think it would. Because the ticks and tick rate (i think that's what it's called) for each client wouldn't be the same, and the fps for each would be different (especially for the client), the physics simulations wouldn't play out at the same rate and the objects wouldn't be synced.

@Zibelas I could interpolate and sync end positions as suggested (great idea); this is essentially like changing the sync interval on a networktransform in unity because i'd have to keep checking and interpolating toward where the position of the object on the server is. but again, in the worst case i want the data as small as possible just in case. It seems that planning for that is best, AND THEN adding all the measures to avoid having to sync too many things.

To be clear: what Zibelas is proposing isn't "just hope the physics comes out the same", it's "do the work to ensure it must come out the same", for example by using a physics engine that guarantees determinism and running it at a fixed timestep, or by choosing one of n pre-canned destruction simulations, etc. Unlike in the real world where the laws of physics are outside our control, in your game YOU create the physics, so if you want the game physics to always come out identically on different clients, you can put in the engineering effort to make that happen.

i totally understand and i appreciate the clarification. before i begin doing that i'd like to be more certain it'll work. one issue i for-see is this. let's say a building fragment hits a moving player. since the players are not perfectly sync in location especially while moving, player will collide with the fragment at slightly different spots on the fragment, which will result in differing resulting velocities for the fragment after the collision.

so even if the destruction physics simulation is perfectly deterministic, anything that falls outside that physics simulation that differs across clients will make the simulations across clients turn out differently. i could send velocity data to clients, but that'd require sending more data which i want to avoid. how would i avoid variations in the simulation given variables like what i mentioned.

i hear what you're saying and i'm not trying to avoid putting in the engineering work, i just don't want to waste a bunch of time; so i'm asking these probing questions. also, i totally agree that avoiding sending constant sync data for all fragments would be tough, but i'm specifically asking if you guys know a method for reducing the size/amount of data sent, JUST IN CASE i need to send a ton of data, which it seems i may. Would you happen to know what method might reduce network package sizes the most?
